# Data retrieved from json output saved into arrays using Gson

Tags: java

I am building a restful web service and also a java client that consumes the web service. The responses from the server sent to the client are in json format. I want to store the attributes and the data from the json string to an array, so I can use the data to build some client operations. Let 's say I have I have a collection of products. The output from the rest server is in this format, and I simply have it in a string variable:

```
String output="{"product":[{"code":"7","name":"book","value":"4.0"},{"code":"3","name":"pen","value":"4.5"},{"code":"9","name":"pencil","value":"5.5"}]}"
```

I have tried to convert the json object to a java object of type Product

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
Product product= gson.fromJson(output,Product.class);
System.out.println(product);
```

The output is:

```
product:[product:null,name:book,code:7,value:4,000000,       
product:null,name:pen,code:3,value:4,500000,  
product:null,name:pencil,code:9,value:5,500000],name:null,code:null,value:null
```

and when I

```
System.out.println(product.product);
```

the output is:

```
[product:null,name:book,code:7,value:4,000000,     
product:null,name:pen,code:3,value:4,500000,   
product:null,name:pencil,code:9,value:5,500000]
```

First question: I don t know why the null values appear, and I can t find a way that I can fix this.

Second question: I have been searching around for days, but I really can t find a way to save these data into an array or a list. I don t want to save them in a java Products object. What I want to do is to have all the attributes together, for example an array of all the values, or the names or all the products.

```
Something like this I have in mind:

String[] names=["book","pen","pencil"];
Integer[] codes=[7,3,9];
Double[] values=[4.0,4.5,5.5];
```

Third question: Should I make these operations (for example calculating the total values) in the server side? Will this be the better way to go?

Fourth question: Is it necessary to duplicate the Products class in the Client? That 's the reason I am not sure that the operations beyond CRUD should absolutely be on the client 's side.

Product class:

```
class Product  {

public String name;
public Integer code;
public Double value;
public List<Product> product;


public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name=name;
}

public Integer getCode()
{
    return code;
}

public void setCode(Integer code)
{
    this.code=code;
}

public Double getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Double value)
{
    this.value=value;
}
public List<Product> getProduct() 
{ 
    return product; 
}
 public void setProduct(List<Product> order) 
 { 
     this.product = product; 
 }
@Override
public String toString() {
 return    String.format("product:%s,name:%s,code:%d,value:%f",product,name,code,value);
      }
}
```

I am using Gson library, because it seems to be the most simple way.

Answer (score 1):

First, the appearance of the "null" values: That is probably due to the way your toString() method works. Just check what it does. If you append a null to a String, it will be printed as literal "null".
Secondly, why don't you want to store your products as Product objects on the client? That's pretty much what object oriented programming is all about, keeping stuff together that belongs together. Just put them all in a Collection and define your methods for iterating over that Collection to get out all the prices, names and whatnot that you need or do whatever you need to do with your products. I see no good reason not to have the Product class in the client. Or rather use a shared project for client and server that contains the class, so you can use it in both wothout having to worry about keeping it in sync.

Your JSON String contains a list, but you try to retrieve a single object. Try this:

```
final List<Product> products = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,
new TypeToken<Collection<Product>>() {
            }.getType());
```

Then you should be able to iterate over the result, e.g. like this:

```
double totalValue=0; 
for (Product product:products) {
    totalValue+=product.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer. So what I should do Is to iterate the Product object and get the values? I am new to object oriented programming btw :P

Comment: btw. why does your Product object have another List of Products inside?

Comment: because  String.format("name:%s,code:%d,value:%f",name,code,value); prints null and I saw a similar example in SO and implemented the List inside :-/